# Hidden property of feature

Tags: feature

If Is Hidden property on the feature designer is set to True then the feature wont appear in the list of features.

Hence the feature is enabled, but cannot be disabled or uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not from the GUI, but it can be Enabled/Disabled via the object model (at least C# and PowerShell)

Comment: Robert, does such a feature (IsHidden=true) get auto activated ?

Comment: That depends on whether you set it to auto activate or not ("Activate on Default")

Comment: Suppose under project properties we have set Activate on Default=FALSE, then, during deploying via PowerShell is there anyway to override this to make it TRUE? Because we cannot see it in UI. Otherwise can we also use PowerShell command to activate the feature by GUID? Are both options possible?

Comment: Not override, no. But you can activate by using `Enable-SPFeature`cmdlet

Comment: Just asking, but I guess we can override the FORCE install via PowerShell even if project properties force: FALSE... Then are you sure that Activate on Default if FALSE cannot be overriden via PowerShell?

Comment: Well.. I'm not 100% sure, but it not something you normally would do. I mean, surely you could update the feature.xml file in the hive and so on